# Strange Behavior In C#: Parsing Strings To Doubles Bug

Tags: c#, type-conversion, string-conversion

**Update:**

Here is a link to a project that fails at be even if it's explicitly a double in VS 2015 CE .NET 4.6.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20941617/Scratchpad.zip

Ok I know how to replicate it. When it breaks on the the explicit operator chunk of code, you just have to copy the string straight out of debug and paste it in 'a' and it will break even though it looks like a normal string.

```
double a = double.Parse("1");
double b = double.Parse("1");
```

**Original:**

Why does 'a' work but 'b' throws an exception: "Input string was not in a correct format."?

```
double a = double.Parse("1");
var b = double.Parse("1");
```

The same exception occurs in the scenario below as well.

```
Number n = (Number)"‎1";
```

Number is a custom data type (struct) I made. It fails to parse the string into a double.

```
public static explicit operator Number(string n)
{
        double x = double.Parse(n);
        return new Number(x);
}
```

What is even more strange is I copied my struct into a new project I made to replicate the errors. But... in the original project with the same struct, it doesn't throw an exception.

I load constants from a text file and convert them to Number just fine. These constants work:

```
pi,3.14159265358979323846,none
π,3.14159265358979323846,none
golden ratio,1.61803398874989484820,none
phi,1.61803398874989484820,none
φ,1.61803398874989484820,none
```

But when it gets to this constant it throws the same exception.

```
Euler's constant,0.577215664901532860606512,none
```

It also throws it on "0.1", but not all the time... It's really confusing, which is why I made a new project, but it behaves differently in the new project for some reason.

I am using .NET 4.6 in all projects. I was using 5.4.2 originally but changed it. The issue appears to be the same in both versions.

Comment: The first code snippet runs without a problem, (http://ideone.com/172M50) so the OP must be trolling us.  Refusing to look any further.

Comment: What makes you think that a custom struct that you made would be capable of casting a string?

Comment: @LukePark that's okay, because he defined an operator for that.

Comment: @MikeNakis ahh I didn't read far enough down..

Comment: There's something really weird going on. Is it possible that the string in 'b' can be different without it showing up in VS? If I copy 'a' and past it over 'b' and change it to say 'var' and 'b' it works. I am going to see if I can zip it and upload it and still get the behavior.

Comment: This is the link. It crashes for me on VS 2015 CE .NET 4.6.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20941617/Scratchpad.zip

Comment: Ok I know how to replicate it. When it breaks on the the explicit operator chunk of code, you just have to copy the string straight out of debug and paste it in 'a' and it will break even though it looks like a normal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the usual copy/paste issue of a hidden character

in your code, the length of "1" for b is 2 characters

the first chacracter is the unicode 8206 while the second one is 49 which is 1

do some cleaning and it should work

Comment: Thank you. So now it's just the operator code block that is acting strange. 
I wanted to test it outside the code block to see if it behaved differently and it did, but somewhere during troubleshooting I copy/pasted from debug and that's when things started to get confusing.

Comment: I assumed the original problem was different, but it appears it was the same issue. I copy and pasted the constants into notepad, saved it, received message that it was unicode and that i would loose information, closed it, opened it and found this:

gamma,?0.577215664901532860606512,none